# Blocking unwanted HttpMethods in web.xml

Tags: http, servlets, tomcat9

I am running two different applications(war files) in single tomcat. those two may contact each other.
Now I want to block some of the HTTP methods for application2. So I have added the following into my web.xml in tomcat config folder,

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name><strong>restricted methods</strong></web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/app2/*</url-pattern>
       <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
       <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint />
 </security-constraint>
```

After adding this also I am not getting 403 response for OPTIONS request. it's giving response as 200. but

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name><strong>restricted methods</strong></web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
       <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint />
 </security-constraint>
```

without mentioning app2 in URL pattern it's giving 403 response for OPTIONS request.

Now my question is how can I block some HTTP methods for my application2 alone?
Ihanks in advance.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Can you please be more specifc what exactly you mean with "application" and which web.xml exactly you was editing? Your question would only make sense if with "application" you actually meant an individual WAR deployment and you was editing Tomcat's own web.xml instead of WAR's own web.xml.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. two different war files and editing the web.xml under tomcat config folder.